# AutoFac / .NET Core - Register DBcontext

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac, ef-core-2.0

I have a new .NET Core Web API project that has the following projects structure:

API -> Business / Domain -> Infrastructure

The API is very thin with only the API methods.  The Business / Domain layer has all my business logic.  And finally, my Infrastructure layer has my DB classes using EF Core 2.0.

I know using .NET Core built-in Dependency Injection I can add a reference from the API project to the Infrastructure project, then add the following code in the StartUp.cs file:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

However, I would like to maintain a more traditional separation of concerns.  So far I have added a module in my Infrastructure layer that attempts to make the registration like so:

```
builder.Register(c =>
        {
            var config = c.Resolve<IConfiguration>();

            var opt = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
            opt.UseSqlServer(config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:MyConnection:ConnectionString").Value);

            return new MyContext(opt.Options);
        }).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The DBContext, however, is not getting registered.  Any class that attempts to access the injected DBContext cannot resolve the parameter.

**Is there a way to register the DBContext in a separate project using AuftoFac in a .NET Core Web API Project?**

Comment: This is better. Looks like my guess was right - you should register `MyContext` class directly, not interfaces that it implements.

Comment: It has been awhile since I used AutoFac.  If you see the accepted answer below you'll see I used .AsSelf().  That solved the issue back in .NET 2.0.  I've moved on to only using MSFT DI at this time.  I'm sure things may have changed on the AutoFac side by now.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you're trying to register `MyContext()` using `AsImplementedInterfaces()`. This is not how DbContext are getting registered usually. You should register and resolve class itself.

Comment: You were correct.  I changed .AsImplementedInterfaces() to .AsSelf() and now its working.  Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `AsSelf()` implied if you leave it out? (assuming no other `AsWhatever()` are attached)

Answer (score 26):

I use Autofac to register both `HttpContextAccessor` and `DbContext`.

```
builder
    .RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>()
    .As<IHttpContextAccessor>()
    .SingleInstance();

builder
    .RegisterType<AppDbContext>()
    .WithParameter("options", DbContextOptionsFactory.Get())
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**DbContextOptionsFactory**

```
public class DbContextOptionsFactory
{
    public static DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> Get()
    {
        var configuration = AppConfigurations.Get(
            WebContentDirectoryFinder.CalculateContentRootFolder());

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        DbContextConfigurer.Configure(
            builder, 
            configuration.GetConnectionString(
                AppConsts.ConnectionStringName));

        return builder.Options;
    }
}
```

**DbContextConfigurer**

```
public class DbContextConfigurer
{
    public static void Configure(
        DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext> builder, 
        string connectionString)
    {
        builder.UseNpgsql(connectionString).UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to change connection string based on request query string. How to access `HttpContext` inside `DbContextOptionsFactory` class? I cannot able to resolve `HttpContextAccessor` inside `DbContextOptionsFactory` since it didn't build when we access `DbContextOptionsFactory`.

Comment: I used middleware to set the dynamic connection string on a DI object and then passed that object into the scoped dbcontext at runtime

Comment: Be very careful with lazy loading in aspnet apps: https://ardalis.com/avoid-lazy-loading-entities-in-asp-net-applications/

Answer (score 8):

Another simple solution for Autofac version 4.8.1

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionStrings:MyConnection:ConnectionString")));

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Populate(services);

        //...
        // Your interface registration
        //...

        builder.Build(Autofac.Builder.ContainerBuildOptions.None);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's an implementation I use - it mimics [EF Core 3.1 registration](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/40c8dbe9d45aa161a912345539675e77d114979d/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L476-L500) with Autofac 4.9.4. Be sure to adjust scopes per your requirements.

```
public void RegisterContext<TContext>(ContainerBuilder builder)
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    builder.Register(componentContext =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = componentContext.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
            var configuration = componentContext.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
            var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptions<TContext>(new Dictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>());
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>(dbContextOptions)
                .UseApplicationServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
                .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"),
                    serverOptions => serverOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null));

            return optionsBuilder.Options;
        }).As<DbContextOptions<TContext>>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.Register(context => context.Resolve<DbContextOptions<TContext>>())
        .As<DbContextOptions>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    builder.RegisterType<TContext>()
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the desired project you can create an extension method that adds the context to the collection

```
public static class MyDataExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyData(this IServiceCollection services) {
        //...

        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        //...
    }
}
```

with that then in your start up it is just a matter of calling the extension exposed from the other project

```
services.AddMyData();

//...other settings
```

The API project is the composition root, so it needs to know all the relevant dependencies anyway. At least with this extension you do not have to make direct reference of the used db context,