# Unable to create an object of type MyDbContext

Tags: c#, autofac, entity-framework-migrations

I'm registering `MyDbContext` using Autofac and it's working fine but when I try to use any of the ef migration commands (e.g., `Add-Migration -Name my-migration`) I get the error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

If I register `MyDbContext` with `IServiceCollection` that error goes away. My Autofac configuration is:

```cs
builder.Register(
    _ =>
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
        var conn = configuration.GetConnectionString(connName);
        var dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(conn);
        var password = configuration.GetPassword(connName);

        dbConnection.ProvidePasswordCallback =
            (host, port, database, username) => password;
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(dbConnection);

        return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    })
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

According to microsoft's docs:

> The tools first try to obtain the service provider by invoking Program.CreateHostBuilder(), calling Build(), then accessing the Services property.

I debugged my app and I was able to activate `MyDbContext` from the `IHost` obtained by calling `IHostBuilder.Build()`. What am I missing, do I need to do something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the solution mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125132/autofac-net-core-register-dbcontext)

```
builder.Register(componentContext =>
    {
        var serviceProvider = componentContext.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
        var configuration = componentContext.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
        var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptions<TContext>(new Dictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>());
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>(dbContextOptions)
            .UseApplicationServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
            .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"),
                serverOptions => serverOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null));

        return optionsBuilder.Options;
    }).As<DbContextOptions<TContext>>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Register(context => context.Resolve<DbContextOptions<TContext>>())
    .As<DbContextOptions>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<TContext>()
    .AsSelf()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: I read that answer but didn't think it would change anything. Now I know I was wrong :)