# How to inject the DBContext of Entity Framework Core to AutoFac

Tags: entity-framework-core, db2, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

We have a requirement to use the Db2 database using .NET Core, for which how to inject the Db2 `DBContext` of Entity Framework Core to AutoFac?

Is the repository pattern good? Or do I need to develop a separate class and then inject that into AutoFac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AutoFac / .NET Core - Register DBcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125132/autofac-net-core-register-dbcontext)

Comment: it is for SQL Server. mine is DB2 with EntityFramework.core

Comment: What is the difference? `UseDb2` insetad of `UseSqlServer`, I think it is too obvious.